# Android keyboard overlaps EditText

Tags: android, android-layout

In one fragment i use this layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/header_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutButtonAdd"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView style="@style/line" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonAdd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/addSrButton"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/layoutButtonAdd"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/progressContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <ProgressBar
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="4dip"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text=""
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/listContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="1dip"
        android:paddingLeft="9dip"
        android:paddingRight="4dip"
        android:paddingTop="1dip" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/internalEmpty"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

To the `android:id="@android:id/list"` i dynamically add needed view (edit text, for example).

Problem is if I click on the EditText for the first time, it takes focus and window adjusts pan correctly. But if I click on the editText which already has focus, keyboard appears but it overlaps needed EditText field (i.e. adjust pan doesn't work correctly).
In my manifest file `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` is set.
`android:minSdkVersion="7"`

I'v read about trick with wrapping layout with `ScrollView`, but i already have element with vertical scroll (LinearLayout).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

try using android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"

Comment: This is not solution for me 'cos I have some views at the bottom of this editText (Button at the bottom of the layout at least)

Comment: oh can you chk this link http://www.vogella.com/blog/2010/10/25/android-windowsoftinputmode/